# C++ program with string data type won't run unless I compile it with -static-libstdc++

Tags: c++, g++, mingw-w64

For some time I didn't compile/run my programs using g++ in cmd and I only used CodeBlocks where I didn't have any problems so I don't know when this started.

So I tried to run a program that I compiled with 'g++ main.cpp' and it either wouldn't run at all, like nothing happened, or [this would pop out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS0iP.png)
From a not so related answer in google I found that adding the -static-libstdc++ flag would fix this but I don't want to do this every time and the OCD in me wants to know why this is happening.

P.s. As mentioned in the title this only happens when the program has the string type in it. I also tried reinstalling Mingw but no luck.

Comment: You probably have a different (older) installation of gcc somewhere in the PATH.

Comment: Check that the program is both compiled and linked using the "g++" front-end.  GCC can compile C++ code when invoked as "gcc", but when linking an executable, "g++" is needed in order to incorporate the standard library (which includes std::string).

Comment: I did have an older installation of Mingw but I made sure to delete it and remove everything from the Path, so the Path also only has the new installation of Mingw. Can Visual Studio or CodeBlocks have something to do with this?

Comment: Manually inspect all folders in %PATH% and make sure you only have one file named libstdc++-6.dll in there, and that it is from the installation of mingw you are using.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thank you, that did the job. I added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  *@n. 'pronouns' m* instructed in the comments, I checked my %PATH% and found LyX, a Latex document processor which I don't even remember using, which for some reason also had the libstdc++-6.dll file. I uninstalled it and that fixed it.